# Heading Expand/Collapse Jquery Working but is Expanded by Default, I need it collapsed by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on a sharepoint site.. I'm completely new to javascript. I have been using a jquery I found to enable an expand/collapse feature that is tied to a heading type. When a heading is clicked, all of the paragraph content beneath the heading expands or collapses.

It works well, the only problem is that when the page loads, all of the content is expanded by default, and then collapses a moment later after the page finishes loading. It looks sloppy when loading so I want to have everything collapsed by default.

I also do not need the function that disables expand/collapse while in edit mode or a wikipage, if that makes this issue any simpler.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
 var inEditMode = Utils.checkPageInEditMode();
 // Prevent the collapsing of <h2> blocks when in SharePoint's [Edit Mode]
 if (!inEditMode) {
 UI.collapseContentHeaders();
 UI.toggleContentHeaders();
 }
 });

var UI = {
 collapseContentHeaders: function () {
 $('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2').each(function (index, value) {
 // Collapses all <h2> blocks 
 {
 $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('h2').slideToggle(100);
 }
 });
 },

 toggleContentHeaders: function () {
 // Toggles the accordion behavior for <h2> regions onClick
 $('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2').click(function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('h2').slideToggle(100);
 });
 }
 }

var Utils = {
 checkPageInEditMode: function () {
 var pageEditMode = null;
 var wikiPageEditMode = null;

// Edit check for Wiki Pages
 if (document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode) {
 wikiPageEditMode = 
document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value;
 }
 // Edit check for all other pages
 if (document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode) {
 pageEditMode = 
 document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;
 }
 // Return the either/or if one of the page types is flagged as in Edit Mode
 if (!pageEditMode && !wikiPageEditMode) {
 return false;
 }
 return pageEditMode == "1" || wikiPageEditMode == "Edit";
}
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: UI.collapseContentHeaders(); UI.toggleContentHeaders(); this is the reason to expand and  collapse after page load , so you need to validate if the content are expand then only collapse work.so after page load you should call collapse and avoid the UI.toggleContentHeaders();

Comment: give the example fiddle for your problem

Comment: Try omitting `.slideToggle(100)` from `collapseContentHeaders()`?

Comment: ... in favour of `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete if statement

```
if (index > 0) {
```

So i has to be olny `$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('h2').slideToggle(100);`